# How to give last class to other element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, callback

I have some list elements with dynamically id changing. Next i give this id's to other element, as a class one by one. So, this is my code:

```
$('#rounded_items li').one({click: function(){
    $('#back_button').addClass(this.id);
}});
```

and `#back_button` receives classes 1, 2, 3, 4 from `#rounded_items li`. How can i grab the last class from `back_button` and give it to `#rounded_items` by click.

Is there any possible to give back the last class from element who receives this class?

Comment: What do you mean by "grab last class from `#back_button`"?

Comment: @Bergi Well, the last class that was added to the button, I presume... the question is, what does "*give it to #rounded_items by click*" mean.

Comment: id's from list elements are changing dinamicly by ajax, i give them as classes to #back_button in some kind of chain: 1,2,3,4. How to grab last class and give it to other element, in that case #rounded_items

Comment: numbers aren't legal CSS classes...

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski Do you mean a FIFO queue? Is what what you want?

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski what are you _actually_ trying to do?  Do these classes actually change the visual appearance, or are you just using the `class` field as a temporary data store?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/last/ you mean this??

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I think he rather means a LIFO queue

Comment: you know what is the problem? we can't understand your english! please explain correctly and post some html and css

Comment: @Bergi Yes. LIFO. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can store it as data

```
$('#rounded_items li').one('click', function(){
    var classes = $('#back_button').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    var last = classes[classes.length-1];
    $.data($('#back_button')[0],'lastclass',last);
    $('#back_button').addClass(this.id);
});

$('#back_button').click(function(){
    var lastclass = $.data($('#back_button')[0],'lastclass');
    $('#rounded_items').addClass(lastclass);
    var classes = $('#back_button').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    $.data($('#back_button')[0],'lastclass',classes[classes.length-3]);
    $('#back_button').removeClass(classes[classes.length-1]);
});
```

you can also try this:

```
   $('#back_button').click(function(){
        var classes = $('#back_button').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
        $('#rounded_items').addClass(classes[classes.length-2]);
        $('#back_button').removeClass(classes[classes.length-1]);
    });
```

Comment: it's work but rounded_items receives all of this class not the last one :(

Comment: replace `$('#rounded_items').addClass(lastclass);` with `$('#rounded_items li#' + lastclass).addClass(lastclass);`

Comment: @Gustonez It will add the class to the `li` whose id is same as `lastclass`, but OP wants to add the class to `#rounded_items`.

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski, what do you mean when you say that you can't repeat it??? maybe you need to remove the class from backbutton `$('#back_button').removeClass(classes[classes.length-1])`??

Comment: i thought he want to toggle the class. but it seems that he want to set back the previous class all the way back everytime he click the back_button!

Comment: ok, everythings is fine but i need also to back 2 steps back, i can't give second time to $('#rounded_items') - i can give one time this class, how can i give it after second click on #back_button

Comment: i'm removing clasess when i'v go back `$('#back_button').removeClass(classes[classes.length-1]);` but i need to recive the last class once again when i click at back button second time, and third time...

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski I am not able to understand what you need, lets say back_button has classes 'a b c d e', so on first click you want to get d, then on second click you want to get c and so on..... or do you want to return d everytime??

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski the second code should work after you remove the class

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15855/discussion-between-lukasz-borawski-and-ankur-mittal)

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to store the ids, not a class attribute!

```
var stack = [];
$('#rounded_items li').one('click',function(){
    stack.push(this.id);
});
$('#back_button').click(function(){
    $('#rounded_items').setClass(stack.pop());
});
```

Comment: i need to give this class after click at back_button

Comment: I am very sure that you should not use the class name to store these values - updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your classes aren't really being used to style anything, as they're not legal CSS identifiers.  If the intent is just to store some state, use `.data`:

```
var $back = $('#back_button');

$back.data('state', []);                   // empty array to store state

$('#rounded_items li').one({click: function() {
    $back.data('state').push(this);        // store clicked element
});

$back.on('click', function() {
    var elem = $back.date('state').pop();  // retrieve last clicked element
    if (elem) {
        // do something with elem...
    }
});
```

If the code is all in the same lexical scope you can just use a local array to store the state without using `.data()`.